# How can i program my software to save its data to a particular server?

Tags: python

I want to develop an messenger type software for windows using python, but i want to make my software to save all the data to a particular server, so please help me how can i ?

Comment: what do you mean by `particular server` ? data always gets saved to a server

Comment: Hello! I'm afraid your question is too broad. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass full directory to file with server address. In my local network I use something like this:

```
s_address = '//192.168.0.250//'
#copy file:
shutil.copy2(file_to_copy, s_address+'folder on network disc')
#create new file and write to it:
with open(s_address+'folder//test1.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    w = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    w.writerow('test')
```

etc